# how to take screenshot of movie you are watching at some intervals?

Tags: debian, video, screenshot

I know that within VLC it is possible to have screenshots of a movie but what if you used mpv or some other tool via which you are watching the movie.

I do remember there is a command-line tool (think it's imagemagick or something else ) through which you can send the video and it will take pictures or screenshots at pre-determined interval. Any help is welcome. Scrot is supposed to help with this, any scrot users out here who could help perhaps ?